Angular 17 Visual Studio Code terminal ng g c component does not work
In Angular 17 working on VSCODE Windows 11 i try to generate a component via terminal ng c header and it doesn't work, i don't get any message in the console and i don't see any files. I tried a lot of answers in Stack Overflow.
I expect to see files or a terminal message.

Did you try "ng g c header" ? Just for curiosity

Thanks, i already tryed it, but it did not worked, but I realized you had to do it in the terminal but with the server off
